# Как говорить об уровнях ведения боя (партер, стойка)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Силовая схватка в партере называется борьбой, а противопоставлен ей "бой в стойке", "бой в положении стоя"?

Comment: У вас явно специфическая терминологии. В классических стилях - борьба в партере и борьба в стойке. Если в каких-то стилях борьба в стойке борьбой не считается, то там и надо спрашивать, как она назівается.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо бы конкретнее обозначить предмет. Возможно, все зависит от конкретного стиля. Но при этом мне не известны виды единоборств, где бы термин "борьба" применялся только для схватки в партере.

У вас явно или нечеткая формулировка или какая-то очень специфическая терминология. В классических и новых стилях (*вольная, греко-римская, дзюдо, самбо, карате, тхеквондо, джиу-джитсу, капоэйра* и проч.) - **борьба в партере и борьба в стойке.** Или термин борьба вообще не применяется (*бокс, рукопашный бой*) - но там обычно и партера как такового нет. В *сумо* тоже нет партера, но есть борьба. Просто борьба, ибо добавлять "в стойке" абсолютно излишне.

Если в каких-то стилях борьба в стойке борьбой не считается, то там и надо спрашивать, как она называется. Мне о таком странном выборе термина не известно.

Хотя, возможно, речь идет о неспортивных (не чисто спортивных) видах единоборств (типа стилей *М1, ММА, UFС и им подобных - или кетча*) или национальных видах, каковых очень много (*борьба на поясах "куреш", бурятско- монгольская борьба "бүхэ барилдаан", якутская "хапсагай"* - и прочая, и прочая...). Там я в терминологии не разбираюсь.